# Opening the Pdf file from JTable by clicking on pdf file name using java

Tags: java, swing, pdf

I have created one button named as file manager and also I created one table. When I click on my file manager I am able to see the list of the pdf files in the table. but clicking on individual file on the table, how can I open my pdf document without giving our pdf file names directly in the program? I have attached by sample code below. There I am able to select the individual row, but I am not able to open the pdf file. I have attached the image. Please check it.

Thanks in advance.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

      String[] r = new String[5];
      String dirPath = "D:\\Pdf\\";
      File dir = new File(dirPath);
      String[] files = dir.list();

      if (files.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("The directory is empty");

      } else {
        for (String aFile : files) {
            System.out.println(aFile);
        }
     }

     DefaultTableModel model =   (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
     model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"aFile"});

     Object[] row = new Object[1];

     for(int i = 0; i <files.length; i++) {
        row[0] = files[i].toString();
        model.addRow(row);
     }

     private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {    

         try {
             int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

             if (row > -1) {

                 String Table_click = (jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
                 jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                 // model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"aFile"});

                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " 
                                           + Table_click);
            }
     } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Start by maintaining the list of `File` objects, don't convert them to `String`, this will make it easier to call `Desktop.open`.  If you need to customise the look of the object, then use a cell renderer instead

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Desktop.open()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) Method.

And put the content of the PDF in a [temp file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and open this

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried with desktop.open() Method, but its showing all the pdf files from the parent drive. but I want to select the single pdf file from the table and open the same.

Comment: @vidyab What did you pass to `Desktop.open`?  Did you pass a `File`/`URL` reference to the physical file or the directory?

Comment: @Thomas Pawlitzki  I did like  [String dirPath = "D:\\Pdf\\";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
      Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
      d.open(dir);], I passed  directory , but passing the name of the file on the code will not help me, I want to click on the file name from the jTable and immediately I want to open the same.

Comment: OH for pity's sake! You need to have **some understanding** of what the code you churn out, does! Replace `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " 
                                           + Table_click);` with `Desktop.open(new File(Table_click));`!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I executed as you said, but I am getting all the Pdf files together, I want to open my pdf file individually by clicking on my pdf file name from jTable

Comment: @vidya b Then you have to pass the File-Object pointing to the PDF file to Desktop.open() not the object pointing to the directory

Comment: @Thomas Pawlitzki can you please tell here how can I do that?

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:\\Pdf\\your_pdf.pdf");

Comment: @Thomas Pawlitzki I can't give the file name in my code, because it should be entered by the user, I am able to do that here, but how can I open that stored pdf files by a single click on the file name from jTable?